# Lookup aggregation query inverse with mongodb (JOIN)

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, lookup

Assuming I have two collections (`actors` and `actions`) with one `actor` having N `actions`. In `actions` collection, I have an `actorId` that refers to `actors` collection.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#unwind-example), I can get all `actions` with their `actor` like this (it works):

```
db.actions.aggregate([
  {
    '$unwind': '$actorId'
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'actors',
      localField: 'actorId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'actor'

    }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': '$actor'
  }
]);
```

Is there a way to do the inverse query? Can I get associated `actions` from `actors`?

```
db.actors.aggregate(/* how can I get actions? */);
```

Comment: Could you post sample data from both the collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way, [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) returns an array of matching documents so to run inverse query you need following aggregation:

```
db.actors.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actions',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'actorid',
            as: 'actions'
        }
    }
]);
```